# OutputCache and RenderAction cache whole page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have a ViewPage that contains `<% Html.RenderAction<MyController>(c => c.SidebarStats()); %>`.  On the controller action for the action SidebarStats I have an OutputCache action filter to cache only that part of the page.  However, the whole page is getting cached and not just that action.

I remember seeing somewhere that this might be a bug with ASP.NET MVC though I'm not sure.  I'm currently using ASP.NET MVC RC1, IIS7, Windows Server 2008 and .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I blogged a [solution to this problem here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx). It's simple, but it only works if you're using the WebFormViewEngine. We will look hard into figuring out what it will take to make this work for all view engines.

Comment: You the man Phil, I knew there had to be an elegant solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @CVertex no. Is this will be fixed in V3, working with Razor view engine?

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft this is a known bug with no known fix.  Only workarounds suggested are to create your own OutputCache action filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using what **Steve Sanderson** made in [his blog](https://blog.stevensanderson.com) and it's very nice:

```
public class ActionOutputCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // This hack is optional; I'll explain it later in the blog post
    private static readonly MethodInfo _switchWriterMethod = typeof (HttpResponse).GetMethod("SwitchWriter",
                                                                                             BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                                                             BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private readonly int _cacheDuration;
    private string _cacheKey;
    private TextWriter _originalWriter;

    public ActionOutputCacheAttribute(int cacheDuration)
    {
        _cacheDuration = cacheDuration;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _cacheKey = ComputeCacheKey(filterContext);
        var cachedOutput = (string) filterContext.HttpContext.Cache[_cacheKey];
        if (cachedOutput != null)
            filterContext.Result = new ContentResult {Content = cachedOutput};
        else
            _originalWriter =
                (TextWriter)
                _switchWriterMethod.Invoke(HttpContext.Current.Response,
                                           new object[] {new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter())});
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (_originalWriter != null) // Must complete the caching
        {
            var cacheWriter =
                (HtmlTextWriter)
                _switchWriterMethod.Invoke(HttpContext.Current.Response, new object[] {_originalWriter});
            string textWritten = (cacheWriter.InnerWriter).ToString();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(textWritten);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Add(_cacheKey, textWritten, null,
                                                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_cacheDuration), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                                                CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
    }

    private string ComputeCacheKey(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var pair in filterContext.RouteData.Values)
            keyBuilder.AppendFormat("rd{0}_{1}_", pair.Key.GetHashCode(), pair.Value.GetHashCode());
        foreach (var pair in filterContext.ActionParameters)
            keyBuilder.AppendFormat("ap{0}_{1}_", pair.Key.GetHashCode(), pair.Value.GetHashCode());
        return keyBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please visit [Steve Sanderson blog's article](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/10/15/partial-output-caching-in-aspnet-mvc/)  for more information.