# .NET MVC 3 OutputCache Html.Action()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `OutputCache(Duration = 60)` on an action and by default I thought child actions rendered with `@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")` would not be cached unless annotated with OutputCache? This worked with MVC 2 but does not seem to be working with MVC 3. If this has changed, how would I set a portion of the page NOT to cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this looks similar, perhaps it will help:

[OutputCache and RenderAction Cache Whole Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606962/outputcache-and-renderaction-cache-whole-page)

Comment: Unfortunately that link doesn't apply to MVC 3. I'm having this same problem on an app I converted from MVC 2 to 3. Anyone else know what might be up with this?  Thanks....

Comment: I use MVC4 and continues with this problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very frustration. It seems like duration should be able to be set to 0 for child actions as you can for normal actions, but because it has to be a positive integer greater than 0 you get a "duration must be a positive number" error if you try to set duration to 0 for child actions. To solve this I decorate child actions with these attributes:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache( Duration = 1, VaryByCustom="Always")]
```

Then I setup the Always custom output cache in the Global.asax.cs by adding the following method:

```
    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
    {
            if (arg == "Always")
            {
                    return DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            }

            return String.Empty;
    }
```

Basically the first attribute is telling MVC that this is a child action (not reachable from outside the app).  The second attribute is saving the cache for 1 second (minimum allowed for child actions) and varying the cache based on my custom Always caching.  In the method in the global.asax.cs, I am trying to make the value returned unique enough that it will never find it in the one second of caching that is happening.  Not bulletproof, but should work for website that don't have a ton of traffic.